# How do I search keyword by form and get the value?

Tags: spring, forms, jsp

Here is My searchVO

```
public class SearchVO {

    String keyword="default";

    public String getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

}
```

And I want to set the SearchVO value each Time I click the button.

```
<div class="wrap bordWrap">

        <form commandName="SearchVO" id="appList" name="appList"
            action="/index2.do" method="post">

    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
            <br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname">
            <br>


            <td colspan="5"><input type="text" class="appNameID" title=""
                value="${SearchVO.keyword} " name="searchKeyword" placeholder="ID 또는 앱 이름을 입력하세요." /></td>

            <p>
                <button value="Search" onclick="formSubmit()">검색</button>
            </p>

        </form>





    </div>
```

is it possible I just set the commnadName as searchVo and set the search keyword?

and my question is I should I get the value from the controller?'

```
@RequestMapping("/index2.do")
public String list(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request, 
        @ModelAttribute("SearchVo")SearchVO searchVo){

    System.out.println("index2");
    System.out.println(searchVo.getKeyword());
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("searchKeyword"));


    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just change the **searchKeyword** field with **keyword** in html to match name with **keyword** property in **SearchVO** class. So that you will get it easily controller.

Change following field name as below.

```
 <td colspan="5"><input type="text" class="appNameID" title=""
                        value="${SearchVO.keyword} " name="keyword" placeholder="ID 또는 앱 이름을 입력하세요." /></td>
```